# How to build a closable panel in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps, user-interface

I'm trying to emulate the sliding panel found on the left-hand side of the maps.google.com page:

[image: Google Maps UI]

A similar panel is found on the [MapQuest](http://open.mapquest.com/) page.

I need the panel to overlap with the page (so that closing the panel doesn't cause a re-draw of the map) and to be open by default when the page loads.

I like this [sliding jQuery login panel](http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/#), but I can't see how to modify it to work from the left rather than the top.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

On both those pages the elements you speak of have

```
position: absolute;
```

If you want to give an absolute position in relation to its parent then set the parent's position to relative.

If you want to position it on the left simply set its left property to:

```
left: 0;
```

So, as in the jQuery sliding panel you linked to, you can then expand and contract the panel without affecting the layout of the page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have any tips on how to make the panel slide left-right, rather than top-bottom? Or can you suggest another jQuery plugin/sample/script which I could use instead?